# Delete button for each element in list using jquery in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I try to associate a delete button for each element of list. The goal is to delete the element of the list when you click on the delete button.
I can not find how we can retrieve the id of the element that corresponds to the line delete button.
Can someone please help me to write a jquery function.

There is the code:

```
<% var i = 1;
            foreach (var item in Model.List)
            {%>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%:Html.TextBox("IdElement"+ i.ToString(), item.Id) %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%:Html.TextBox("NameElement"+ i.ToString(), item.Name) %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input  type="button" id="ButtonDelete" name="ButtonName" value="Delete" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <%}%>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the answer.**

```
<input  type="button" id="ButtonDelete" name="Information" value="Delete" onclick="GetIds(this);"/>

function GetIds(sender) {
    var IdElement = $($(sender).parent().parent()).find('input').val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. By the way, your Deletebutton must have an unique id, which is not the case here.

```
$("input[value='Delete']").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("input:first").text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

dear first must unique id for every button, second u can do this add extra class like this.

```
<input  type="button" id="ButtonDelete" class="DelButton" name="ButtonName" value="Delete" />
```

and then call this jquery function u will get current id.

```
$('.DelButton').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below steps to achieve but I'll be suggesting with a link instead of a button.

Steps:

1. Create an action method for delete operation with the input parameter as the id of the element to delete. And after deleting redirect to the actual view that show that list table.
2. Replace your button by link with the url pointing to the action method created in step 1 with the query string id for that action method to delete that element.

So that on clicking the link respective action method will hit and delete the record from database and redirect back to the list view.

Note: You may use bootstrap css to style your link as button. Refer [Get boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons)